# Ubuntu Nvidia Drivers 13.10 Installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I've got a problem with installing Nvidia drivers for 13.10.

(Graphics Card: Nvidia 675mx)

At the moment I've been installing the drivers with...

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

I then reboot back to Ubuntu to find that 13.10 will just freeze on the startup screen and I then have to purge nvidia in order to reload the inital Noueveu drivers.

Anybody got any suggestions to sort this problem?

Comment: Try sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common. If that does not solve your problem, you will have to look into /var/log/Xorg.0.log, and post the parts that signal errors

Comment: Just to give information, decided to reload on Ubuntu, but on 12.04 LTS and it automatically recognized the nvidia driver for installation and installed it no problem. Which indicates it may somehow lack support for 13.10 Gnome. Despite being considered supported!

Answer (score 0):

[Did you configure your xorg.conf.d?](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#configure)

[Maybe removing nouveau might solve it? (This link also has a troubleshooting section.)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Removing_Nouveau_.28advanced.2BAC8-expert_users.29)

Comment: Ok i've tried your sugguestion and the same problem happens again. My gig also has Intel Intergrated graphics built into it, could this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to install nvidia 540m driver on Mint and I did it with Bumblebee, it works but gives low fps and I cant figure out why.
Try this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation